# Discovering tables on an Oracle Database return an empty list

Tags: oracle, iccube

When creating a connection to an Oracle database in icCube 'Select existing DB Tables' is returning an empty list of tables.

The connection is fine and I can query the schema creating SQL queries.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The user is used as the schema name, but Oracle uses upper case as default for the schema names. The connection uses the user that is case insensitive.

Just, change the name of your user to the upper case version :  USER_1